# What are the commonly suitable words between these

Tags: word-request

I want to say 'let's get started' but after this I don't know what prepositions are commonly suitable between 'let's get started' and 'doing homework.' I guess maybe 'with' is common.

Please let me know them from this restricted context!

https://www.cambridgeinternational.org/support-and-training-for-schools/teaching-cambridge-at-your-school/getting-started-with/

Comment: I'm not sure why you're suggesting 'at', when 'with' is in the URL and is used in all the examples on the page the URL leads to. What's wrong with 'let's get started with doing homework"? (Imo it sounds better to say "let's get started with homework")

Comment: You could also say "Let's get started doing homework."

Comment: Also "Let's get started on the homework."

Comment: @JMP Sorry, I'm poor at editing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Let's get started with doing homework.*

is okay but doesn't sound idiomatic.

Here's what a native might say

*Let's get started with our homework.*

*Let's get started on our homework.*

*Let's make a start with our homework.*

*Let's start doing our homework.*

*Let's start doing some homework.*

*Let's start our homework.*

*Let's get started with doing some homework.*

*Let's get started with doing our homework.*

*Let's start doing homework.*